# How can I compress my $path on Windows?

Tags: powershell

Windows has a 260 character limit for the path. I've already blown way past it, and it's aggravating. I'd like to find some way to bypass that.

So far, I've had the idea of writing a script in powershell that would get my path variable, parse it, and then set the path with windows shortpath representations of all strings inside.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Function Get-ShortName
{
    BEGIN { $fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject }
    PROCESS
    {
        If ($_.psiscontainer)
            {$fso.getfolder($_.fullname).ShortName}
        ELSE 
            {$fso.getfile($_.fullname).ShortName} 
    } 
}

function Get-ShortPath {
    begin { $fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject }
    process {
        if ($_.psiscontainer) 
            {$fso.getfolder($_.fullname).shortpath}
        else
            {$fso.getfile($_.fullname).shortpath}
    }
}
```

I'm a total beginner to powershell, and now I'm stumped as to how to parse the semicolon delimited list that $env:path returns and turn that into something I can pass to my Get-ShortPath functions. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not correct that the Path environment variable is limited to 260 characters (see [What is the maximum length of an environment variable?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/03/9957320.aspx)).

Comment: Hmm. I was installing CMake, and the installer complained to me that it could not add itself to my path. Other programs have also complained that they could not append to my user path. When I looked up reasons for this, they all pointed to my PATH environment variable being too long. Are you aware of any other reasons this could be happening?

Comment: It's always helpful to first search for the exact error message.

Comment: In fact, I did shorten my path environment variable, and the error went away. I believe now that the problem is with the length of the path. Whether or not there is a 260 char limit I'm not sure, but there is a limit of some sort.

Comment: Perhaps there's a 260-character Path environment variable limitation in the installer for whatever you are installing, but there's no such limitation in the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already noted, the value of `$env:PATH` is a semicolon-separated list.

To split it up, use the [`-split` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx):

```
$Paths = $env:PATH -split ";"
```

Since you haven't declared any named or positional parameters in your functions, you'll have to pipe the strings to them:

```
@($env:PATH -split ";") | Get-ShortName
```